# BEFORE TRIGGER on DELETE statement

Tags: mysql

Just a question, based on some current events. Is it possible and useful to set a trigger on MySQL databases, before executing specific DELETE statements?

While having periodically back-ups is a must, I thought it might be useful to make the DELETE statement more safe, by creating a back-up before actually executing the DELETE statement, for example (like a pre-commit in github, might check for syntax issues before actually committing the code).

Is it possible and recommended to have such triggers? Like I have worked with Database migrations earlier, and the problem with rollbacks was actually you executed a DELETE statement on a column and removed the new data which was added as well. I thought it would be nice to have a (partially) back-up of the data which will be deleted.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a lot of cases of incorrect deletes where you need to retrieve the data? Do a lot of people have access to delete data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways.  All "work":

- Add a `deleted` column.  (This may have performance problems in the long run.)
- Have the application move the row to another table.  (Poor man's Trigger; error prone.)
- Trigger that copies the row to another table.  (Clumsy, slow, needs transaction.)  And, as you ask, what about the deleting the row.
- Stored Procedure to "delete" a row.  (Users must call it; need to deny `DELETE` `PRIVILEGE` to everyone except the Procedure.)
- Application procedure.
- My preference for big, multi-user, applications:

I like the "database layer" in the application.  Instead of letting the users perform actual SQL statements, require them to call APIs in application code (PHP/Java/whatever).  This way, changes to the underlying schema can be changed with little or no retraining of the users.

If the API is "Delete(key)", then the "layer" could deal with a new `deleted` column, or moving the row to new table or calling a stored proc instead of issuing `DELETE FROM tbl ...`.  Etc.

And if I decide that the solution picked is less than perfect, I can change it without even informing the users.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer, very useful! I like the idea of revoking the DELETE privilege (and perhaps the DROP privilege as well) to protect users from accidentally deleting rows and/or tables. Guess we should consider that, and use an extra "delete" column as much as possible.